# xsd. Extend a type with unordered elements set

Tags: xml, xsd, xsd-validation

I've got the following elements structure in my .xsd file:

```
<xs:complexType name="the_rootest" abstract="true">
 <xs:sequence>
     <xs:element name="info" type="complex_type_here"/>
 </xs:sequence>
     <xs:attribute name="Name" type="cpo:string"/>
</xs:complexType>

<xs:complexType name="object" abstract="true">
<xs:complexContent>
    <xs:extension base="the_rootest">
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="is_working" type="cpo:bool"/>
            <xs:element name="has_errors" type="cpo:bool"/>
            <xs:element name="state" type ="cpo:string"/>
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:extension>
</xs:complexContent>
</xs:complexType>

<xs:complexType name="extended_object">
<xs:complexContent>
    <xs:extension base="object">
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="is_zero" type="cpo:bool"/>
            <xs:element name="complex" type="another_complex_type_here" />
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:extension>
</xs:complexContent>
</xs:complexType>

<xs:complexType name="one_more_extended">
<xs:complexContent>
    <xs:extension base="object">
        <xs:sequence>
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:extension>
</xs:complexContent>
</xs:complexType>
```

I've got object with a "extended_object" type in an xml file, which has following fields order

```
info
Name
is_working
has_errors
is_zero
complex
state
```

As you can see, "state" field is standing at the end of the object elements. 
The question is how should I correct my schema to make this object valid?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The usual way to allow unordered elements in a content model is to use `xs:all`.

However, `xs:all` cannot be extended.

Therefore, if you wish to create a new element whose content model resembles an existing element but may have additional elements that can be in a different order than the existing element, your only option is simply to create a new content model independent of the original.  (The type definitions of the child elements can certainly be shared, at least.)

XSD's design is not perfectly orthogonal and consistent.  This is one area where seemingly reasonable expectations cannot be met.  On the bright side, unorderedness tends to be overrated in practice, and a comment in one declaration documenting a dependency with another is nonideal but viable.

Answer (score 0):

If you use XML Schema 1.1, you can use an extension with `xs:all` like so (I modified the schema to make it work on my side with standard types):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xs:schema
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
  xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
  xmlns:vc="http://www.w3.org/2007/XMLSchema-versioning"
  vc:minVersion="1.1">
    <xs:complexType name="the_rootest" abstract="true">
        <xs:all>
            <xs:element name="info" type="xs:string"/>
        </xs:all>
        <xs:attribute name="Name" type="xs:string"/>
    </xs:complexType>

    <xs:complexType name="object" abstract="true">
        <xs:complexContent>
            <xs:extension base="the_rootest">
                <xs:all>
                    <xs:element name="is_working" type="xs:boolean"/>
                    <xs:element name="has_errors" type="xs:boolean"/>
                    <xs:element name="state" type ="xs:string"/>
                </xs:all>
            </xs:extension>
        </xs:complexContent>
    </xs:complexType>

    <xs:complexType name="extended_object">
        <xs:complexContent>
            <xs:extension base="object">
                <xs:all>
                    <xs:element name="is_zero" type="xs:boolean"/>
                    <xs:element name="complex" type="xs:string" />
                </xs:all>
            </xs:extension>
        </xs:complexContent>
    </xs:complexType>

    <xs:complexType name="one_more_extended">
        <xs:complexContent>
            <xs:extension base="object">
                <xs:sequence>
                </xs:sequence>
            </xs:extension>
        </xs:complexContent>
    </xs:complexType>

    <xs:element name="element" type="extended_object"/>
</xs:schema>
```

This XML document validates successfully:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<element xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="test.xsd"
 >
    <info>test</info>
    <is_working>true</is_working>
    <has_errors>true</has_errors>
    <is_zero>true</is_zero>
    <complex>true</complex>
    <state>true</state>
</element>
```

Comment: Here I see an error: "An all group is only allowed at the top level of the content model.". So this variant is not suitable for me.

Comment: Yes, this is what XML Schema 1.0 would say, as kjhughes explains. So it probably means that the software you are using does not support 1.1 unfortunately.

Comment: Thanks. May be you know, is there the way to make "state" field not being validate?